# How do I control footnotes' indentation in LaTeX?

Tags: latex

The first line of my footnotes is indented. Using `\noindent` doesn't help. How do I get it unindented?

Comment: Try http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DNA Isn't latex on-topic on SO?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic says that questions on LaTeX should be directed to http://tex.stackexchange.com/ (although there are nearly 5000 questions here with that tag...)

Answer (score 56):

Use [footmisc](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/footmisc?lang=en) package

```
\usepackage[hang,flushmargin]{footmisc}
```

> The 'hang' option flushes the footnote marker to the left margin of 
>   the page, while the 'flushmargin' option flushes the text as well. The 
>   documentation displays some other options that you could fiddle with 
>   to obtain the results you require.

from [LatexUsersGroup](http://groups.google.com/group/latexusersgroup/msg/4f6f28fcc509a48f) written by [Werner Grundlingh](http://groups.google.com/groups/profile?enc_user=NZmcRRUAAACsD9wHesksMKVM1LA-bE-_9h3i3SmjGmAJbX05nZ-8fQ)